# TEXT formula reserved letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use the following formula (my excel is in german) :

```
=TEXT(HEUTE(),"tt.mm.jjjj")
```

let's say I send this formula to a colleague in the US (the formula text, not the workbook), this would not work since he has to use:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

I would like to find a list of all these operators or reserved letters by language. Does such a list exist ?

Comment: [This](https://en.excel-translator.de/) may be if use

Comment: We had a similar issue once, we used a function to get the system settings then choose the correct format&letters from a list...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad well the excel translator site does not translate the arguments, when I translate TEXT(heute(),"tt.mm.jjjj") from german to english it returns TEXT(TODAY(),"tt.mm.jjjj") (what will not work)

Comment: @SolarMike can you please tell me where you did get that list from ?

Comment: here https://en.excel-translator.de/text/ there is a whole list of MS Help for the Text function, and it displays the letters used for each language. I will compile it and post it here

Comment: We asked the engineers in each country we were working with to tell us the format they used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collected the information from the official MS help below, if this can help somebody:

```
de_DE   tt-MM-jjjj
de_CH   tt-MM-jjjj
fr_FR   jj-MM-aaaa
cs_CZ   dd-MM-rrrr
da_DK   dd-MM-åååå
es_ES   dd-MM-aaaa
el_GR   hh-mm-eeee
et_EE   pp-KK-aaaa
fi_FI   pp-MM-vvvv
hr_HR   dd-MM-gggg
hu_HU   nn-MM-éééé
it_IT   gg-MM-aaaa
nl_NL   dd-MM-jjjj
pl_PL   dd-MM-rrrr
pt_BR   dd-MM-aaaa
ru_RU   ДД-MM-ГГГГ
sv_SE   dd-MM-åååå
tr_TR   gg-MM-yyyy
```

there were other locales but they use the standard dd.mm.yyyy